# vimでカーソル位置の単語を検索する場合にフォーカスが次から開始する

Tags: vim

vim（正確にはVSCode拡張vim）でカーソル位置の単語を検索するために`*`を押すと、
次にヒットする単語の位置にフォーカスが移動します。

単語箇所を確認しながら単純な置換や、テキストオブジェクトを利用した編集をする際に
1番目の単語から操作したいケースが多いため、`*` -> `N`と続けて押しています。

ファイル全体に対する編集ではなく、カーソル以下のメソッド内だけを対象にしたいため、2番目の該当箇所から編集する場合、頻出する文字列の場合に都合が悪くなってしまいます。

`*`のキーマップを`*` -> `N`へ変更することで対処できるように思いますが、
なぜ次にヒットする単語の位置からフォーカスが始まるのでしょうか。
何か意図があってこのような動作になっているのか、また他に代替操作などが存在しているのでしょうか。

Comment: VSCodeの拡張ということで、どこまでvimと同等の操作ができるかわかりませんが、「1番目の単語から操作したいケース」の、その操作内容まで書いていただければ、何か良い操作を提案してもらえるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

作者（Bramさん）に聞いてみないことには完全に憶測の域を出ないですが、 `/` の検索に合わせたんだと思います。

たぶん当初は `*` も検索として使うことを想定して実装されたと思うのですが、実際にはマーカー（その単語をハイライトして周りの同じ単語を探す）として使う人が多くなってしまったことによって生まれる違和感だと思います。

マーカーとして使っている多くの人は `*` に `*N` 割り当てていると感じています。（私もそう）

Answer (score 0):

"カーソル位置の単語" というのは今まさに目の前に表示されているので自明、だから次にヒットした単語からの検索…という挙動なのではないでしょうか。